# Can't sort array: "Ambiguous reference to member '<'"

Tags: swift, sorting, operators

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric {
    func closest(to givenValue: Element) -> Element {
        let sorted = self.sorted(by: <)

        let over = sorted.first(where: { $0 >= givenValue })!
        let under = sorted.last(where: { $0 <= givenValue })!

        let diffOver = over - givenValue
        let diffUnder = givenValue - under

        return (diffOver < diffUnder) ? over : under
    }
}
```

In line 3 of this example code, Xcode gives me the incomprehensible error message `Ambiguous reference to member '<'`, along with this great list:

[image: list of like a dozen "Found this candidate" entries]

What am I supposed to do here? I just want this array to get sorted.

Comment: Also, you should probably check if *array is not empty*, and throw some meaningfull error. Otherwise you will get uncontrollable crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare `Element` to be `Comparable`:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric & Comparable {
```

Comment: Oof, that was it, thanks. I couldn't find any guidance on how to use multiple constraints in Apple's documentation.

Comment: FWIW, it's called a __protocol composition type__. Here is the relevant section in the language reference: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID454

Answer (score 2):

In

```
let sorted = self.sorted(by: <)
```

you're not giving a boolean function for the function to use. Maybe try replacing it with :

```
let sorted = self.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
```

Comment: That is a valid way to sort arrays: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you have defined your `Element` as Numeric only where `>` will work with `Comparable`.

Do it as:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric, Element: Comparable {
    func closest(to givenValue: Element) -> Element {
        //... your code here ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into a similar problem stemming from the type inference when chaining multiple higher order functions (sort, map, etc), when I found this post and I couldn't help but notice the inefficiency of your function.

Here is an example of how you can implement this same function using binary search, massively reducing the time it takes to execute on large datasets:

```
extension Array where Element: Numeric & Comparable {
    func closest2(to target: Element) -> Element {
        if target <= self[0] {
            return self[0]
        }
        if target >= self[count - 1] {
            return self[count - 1]
        }

        var i = 0
        var j = count
        var mid = 0

        while i < j {
            mid = (i + j) / 2

            if self[mid] == target {
                return self[mid]
            }

            if target < self[mid] {

                if mid > 0 && target > self[mid - 1] {
                    return getClosest(val1: self[mid - 1], val2: self[mid], target: target)
                }

                j = mid

            } else {
                if mid < count - 1 && target < self[mid + 1] {
                    return getClosest(val1: self[mid], val2: self[mid + 1], target: target)
                }

                i = mid + 1
            }

        }

        return self[mid]
    }

    private func getClosest(val1: Element, val2: Element, target: Element) -> Element {
        return target - val1 > val2 - target ? val2 : val1
    }
}
```